# Feedback in Sampled Data System

Tags: control-theory

I have a feedback loop as shown in figure. Broken link represents sampling and signal with asterisk as superscript represents discrete signal. ZOH is the abbreviation for zero order hold operation.

[image: sampled Data System]

I tried solving for the closed loop transfer function but after following rules given in the books on Digital Control, I was able to come up with

\begin{equation}
{C^*} = \frac{{Z(G{R})}}{{1 + Z(ZOHG)H(z)}}.
\end{equation}

I have following questions

1. Is it possible to get closed loop transfer function which can be written as $\frac{{{C^*}}}{{{R^*}}}$?
2. Is it right if one converts $H(z)$ to continuous transfer function using tustin or other method, and writes a closed loop transfer function in continuous form?

Comment: Your questions seems ambiguous. The signal R* is discrete and the output of the ZOH is continuous. You are taking the difference of both. This does not seem to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the fault in block diagram. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is somewhat confusing. First what is R*? I am assuming you mean R(s), the reference signal. Furthermore, you are interested in the control output C(s)?

Firstly, regarding your second question, it is far more customary to start of with a continuous time model and discretize it using Tustin or other methods then the other way around. So let start from that...
Followingly
[image]

Herein, r is the reference signal, e is the error signal, u is the control output signal, y is the output of plant. Furthermore, C(s) is the transfer function describing the controller and P(s) is the transfer function describing the behavior of the plant.

Now we can easily derive the transfer functions from several signals to other signals. You requested the transfer function which describes the behavior from the reference signal to the control output.

$$\frac{U(s)}{R(s)} = CS(s) = \frac{C(s)}{1 + P(s)C(s)}$$

This is also called the controller sensitivity. When you would look at the bode diagram you would see were the controller is most effective.

This answers your first question because this is the same as in discrete time

$$\frac{U(z)}{R(z)} = CS(z) = \frac{C(z)}{1 + P(z)C(z)}$$

Because you will choose either to discretize $P(s)$ by a ZOH discretization scheme and $C(s)$ by, for instance, Tustin.

Comment: ,Thank you for the answer. By R*, I mean Laplace transform of r*(t) (discrete signal). In most of the digital control books they have followed this notation. Also in these books they have found the closed loop transfer function for the block diagram that you have mentioned. But I want to know whether it is applicable to the block diagram I have given.

Comment: @Sheldon, if r*(t) is a discrete signal then R* = R(s) cannot be the Laplace transform of r*(t). Using Laplace transform you can transform a continuous time function to the frequency domain. Using the Z transform you can transform a discrete time function to the frequency domain. Furthermore, if you look correctly, you see that C(s) in your diagram equals u and R(s) equals r. You did not answer my question about that if G(s) is the controller or the plant. Anyhow, if G(s) is the actual plant (not the controller) then the equation stays almost the same, only switch C(z) by P(z)